# set the "from" correctly when using nodemailer always recieve my email

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer

If I send an email and recieve it, it shows the from and to email are same although I set the from email as a different mail. Why I set this but does not show correctly the email that I set ?

```
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 587,
      auth: {
        user: "kontakt@xxx.de", // generated ethereal user
        pass: "xxxx", // generated ethereal password
      },
    });

    // send mail with defined transport object
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: email, // sender address
      to: "kontakt@xxx.de", // list of receivers
      subject: "Kontaktanfrage xxx", // Subject line
      text: issue, // plain text body
      html: `
        <p>Name: ${name}</p><br>
        <p>Anliegen: ${issue}<p>
      `, // html body
    });
```